# What's a simple example of how Mongolian is radically dependent-marking?

Tags: linguistic-typology, mongolian

In Johanna Nichols' book [*Linguistic Diversity in Space and Time*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=52WlLWgPG-oC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=mongolian%20japanese%20dependent&source=bl&ots=OnDOddKApn&sig=Lg2b4-542ysPAgGgI6RYrWql08w&hl=en&ei=vxvdTtaLGdG6hAfjgb3WBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=mongolian%20japanese%20dependent&f=false), I came across the passage on page 146, where she asserts that Japanese, Mongolian, Dyirbal, and Yawelmani are all radically dependent-marking. Having studied a bit of Japanese, I can imagine what she is talking about. But I'd like to see what this looks like in Mongolian in practice. Can someone provide a simple example (sentence-length perhaps)?

For those unfamiliar with the distinction between head-marking and dependent-marking, a copy of Nichols' classic 1986 paper on the topic can be downloaded [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/bcitko/LING%20480/nichols.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple one from [this paper](http://www.ilg.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/C2/publications/Guntsetseg.pdf):

```
Bold naiz   ohin-ig-oo    uns-sen.
Bold friend girl-Acc-Poss kiss-Pst.
‘Bold kissed his girlfriend.’
```

There are two head-dependent relations in this sentence. One is the relationship between the verb (a head), 'uns-...' and its arguments (dependents), 'Bold' and 'naiz ohin-...-oo'. The other is between a possessor noun (dependent), 'Bold' and the possessed noun (head), 'naiz ohin-...'. In both cases, the relationship is marked on the dependent; Accusative case is marked on the object noun, and possessive is marked on the possessed noun, the two of which happen to be the same thing.

Comment: Huh? If 'naiz ohin-...' is the head, as you write, the relationship is marked on the head, no?